# Efficient comparison of unsigned ints (C++ compiler optimization)

Tags: c++, assembly, optimization, x86, micro-optimization

I want to get the most speed-optimal code out of this frequently run comparison:

```
int Object::Compare(Object *other) {
    if(id < other->id) return -1;
    if(id > other->id) return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

The `id` var is an unsigned 32-bit integer.

What I'm finding is that even with speed optimizations turned on via a pragma (ordinarily the debug build doesn't use optimizations), I'm still seeing awful inefficiency in the assembly where it's reading the id vars twice and comparing twice, even though I only need the comparison to be done once.

Variations on this code have not helped. In this specific case I'm compiling in Visual C++ and looking at the output, although the code is meant to also compile for Linux environments (still x86 though). What I'm wondering is, is there a better way to structure this so the compiler can understand it should only compare once and then use comparison flags to handle the rest?

Even better would be if I can get any non-branching instructions like `cmov` in play. Any thoughts?

Comment: Use a compiler that doesn't suck. https://godbolt.org/z/dqjGGYs4r is a version simplified to take two `int *` args, to simulate your arg and `this`.   clang and GCC only run `cmp` once; clang branches for `-1`, and then uses `setcc`.  GCC uses setcc+cmov.  Of course if you're branching on the result, and this can inline, i.e. it's not hidden behind virtual function dispatch, then have a look at the callsite, not a stand-alone version of this function.  (Optimizations need to be on, obviously.)

Comment: That's a pretty straightforward code, besides adding `const noexcept`, I'd leave as it is. What `pragma` are you using?

Comment: MSVC's code-gen loads once.  It repeats the `cmp` but that lets it use `xor`-zeroing to zero-extend the setcc result.  Otherwise basically the same strategy as clang's: https://godbolt.org/z/s8cs59h78.  Are you sure you enabled optimization properly for MSVC?

Comment: It would help if you provided a [mcve] - a small but complete sample of code that presents your concern, including description of the compiler options.   With a disconnected fragment like you have supplied, there are all sorts of possibilities (e.g.  `id` is a `volatile` member,  the `id` member is a type with overloaded comparison operators or volatile members, etc etc).

Comment: "*with speed optimizations turned on via a pragma*" - what pragma?

Comment: How about `return (other->id < id) - (id < other->id);`?

Comment: What’s wrong with returning the difference?

Comment: @zdf: Because that wouldn't have the compare-result info if the subtraction wraps.  It takes up to N+1 bits to hold the full result of an N-bit addition or subtraction.  That's why (in x86 asm) the unsigned below condition is CF == 1 (carry-out = borrow), not SF == 1  (MSB).  You *could* return `id - int64_t(other->id)` as a signed integer, if the inputs are actually unsigned *int*, i.e. a narrower type.  That would be efficient on a 64-bit system, since you just zero-extend both inputs (usually free after inlining) and subtract.

Comment: @PeterCordes I assumed a cast to a larger signed integer; sorry. [`return int64_t(a) - int64_t(b)`](https://godbolt.org/z/e46Ersaej).

Comment: @zdf: Ok yes, that works.  But you forgot to enable optimization, and you defeated the purpose by casting back to `int`.  You have to actually return `int64_t`.  https://godbolt.org/z/ja3Yecac6.  Enabling optimization makes the problem obvious in the asm: still only a 32-bit subtraction with your original.  I included a fixed version that is way more efficient than setcc/cmov.

Comment: @PeterCordes The code in question is 32-bit.

Comment: Just wanted to add that apparently the pragma is useless. The only way I can really tell what's going on is to get ASM output from the release code generation. I hate having to do that because it's much harder to see changes, but the pragma has been a complete failure.

Comment: I've included the suggestion by @Scheff in this test: https://godbolt.org/z/qohqEffhT. That version is branchless, but is it in fact faster? How would I be able to test that effectively?

Comment: @LummoxJR: Oh, you're using the Windows meaning of "x86", where you specifically mean obsolete 32-bit mode.  Not the CPU-architecture meaning where it means x86 including extensions like x86-64, as opposed to totally different ISAs like AArch64.

Comment: @LummoxJR: [What considerations go into predicting latency for operations on modern superscalar processors and how can I calculate them by hand?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51607391).  MSVC's version of materializing both the booleans with `cmp`/`sbb`/`neg` (at least 3 cycle dependency chain) and then subtracting them doesn't look very good compared to GCC's `setcc` / `cmov`.  SBB and CMOV are both 2-uop instructions on Intel before Broadwell, but MSVC's uses SBB (and everything else) twice, taking more instructions for front-end throughput.  And I think worse critical-path latency.

Comment: But it remains to be seen how this would optimize into a caller that did `if (px->Compare(py) >= 0) swap(...)` or something; you want something that can inline and reduce to a `cmp / jae`.  If that's your normal use-case, then the stand-alone version that actually creates a boolean is less important.